# Are these studs supporting the stairs?

Tags: stairs, crawlspace

Planning on building a cupboard under the stairs i was going to leave this section but the plasterboard was damp (Prob from cats water bowl spilling or something). So i thought i may as well make use of all the space under the stairs but i was wondering if any of these studs are supporting the stairs. I don't think they are but this is an old house so who nos. I would be happy just removing the front two and to be honest one of the front two has a big split in it so if they are offering support they wont be for much longer xD

Many thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can tell better than us from the photos you provided. Are the stairs attached to those studs? The bigger question, though, is whether those studs are supporting something in the roof.

Comment: They strengthen the stairs by preventing flexing

Comment: I agree with isherwood that they may be supports for the roof, why use 4x4's for support. It can still be done but you may need a larger header to carry the load. Being able to see the connecting point may help and the entry upstairs would be helpful. As far as a crack in that old post, don't get two eager to pull it. Unless you have a bunch to spend you almost cannot get high density lumber any more many trees today are only 50-70 years old but back in the 50's and before they were well over 100-150 years old and what is sold today as #2 was burned to create steam to run the mill.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the studs for better access to the space for storage, that I did for my neighbor, you could install a header supported by jack studs that will hold the weight above. You may need to consult a professional to engineer the opening the header and supports. My neighbor now has a lot of storage space he previously did not have.

Comment: For a span that small, a double 2x6 (on edge) should be adequate. That's what I'd be doing unless you have more than one story above, in which case I'd go 2x8 or 2x10. Everything's open and accessible, so just do it.